# BitcoinJ library causing my app to be unable to run on mobile device

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I am trying to use an app which uses the BitcoinJ library to talk to the Bitcoin blockchain. I have added the following to my build.gradle file but when I do the library is available in android studio within my Kotlin files but it causes the application to fail when installing the APK to run on my phone. What am I missing that would allow it to run in my mobile application?

```
implementaion 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.4'
```

Comment: Do you get any error in logcat or during the gradle build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging I found that if I included the following in my build.gradle it solved the issue.

```
implementation('org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.4') {
    exclude module: 'scrypt'
}
```